# Which of the following is a lattice?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory, lattice-orders

[image]

As far as I know, in a lattice every element should have at-least one least upper bound and one greatest lower bound.

In figure 2) Every element has LUB and GLB, even b and c have GLB d.

In figure 3) Even here every element has LUB and GLB.

So both should be lattice according to me.But the answer is none of them are lattice.

So, should LUB and GLB of a particular pair of elements be unique ? I have not seen unique word anywhere in the definition of a lattice. Also, why is (ii) figure not a lattice ?

Comment: Recall the definition of a lub: $x$ is the lub of $A$ if and only if $x\geq A$ and for all $y$ such that $y\geq A, x\leq y$. In figure (ii), what element satisfies this for $A = \{e, d\}$ ? Prove yourself that a lub (if it exists) is unique

Comment: I think it's because of the point d. But I am not completely sure.

Comment: There is a good reason why that element is called greatest lower bound (resp. least upper bound), is that it is the greatest (resp. the least) of the upper bounds (resp, lower bounds), because these are unique, as Max suggests you to prove. What you have in these cases is at least one common upper bound and one common lower bound, but not unique for some pairs, so these are **not** lattices.

Comment: @amrsa, So, in figure ii) lower bound of {b,c} is {d,e} but maximum{d,e} is null because e is not related to d right? if there would have been an edge from e to d then GLB would be d and thus ii) is a lattice right?

Comment: Precisely, but in that case, we wouldn't have the edges connecting $e$ and $b$, and $e$ and $c$, since they would be redundant.

Comment: Yeah true, thanks !